Is there any way to make my messages form the input chat box to disappear after i click send?
I am new into programming, I want to learn more with projects but I run into some problems that I can't figure out. I got this code with a chatbox on a website, I added recently the emojionearea css and js and after this I cant send the message via 'enter' button and the text is not disappearing after I press 'Send' button. I am really stuck.
room.html
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}
<head>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/emojionearea.min.css') }}"
  />
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <!-- Include EmojiPicker.js -->
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/emojionearea.min.js') }}"></script>
</head>

<div class="message-box">
  <h2>Chat Room: {{ code }}</h2>
  <div class="messages" id="messages"></div>
  <div class="inputs">
    <input
      type="text"
      rows="3"
      placeholder="Message"
      name="message"
      id="message"
    />
    <!-- Emoji picker button -->
    <button type="button" name="send" id="send-btn" onClick="sendMessage()">
      Send
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var socketio = io();

  function handleKeyPress(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      sendMessage();
    }
  }

  const messages = document.getElementById("messages");

  const createMessage = (name, msg) => {
    const content = `
    <div class="text">
        <span>
        <strong>${name}</strong>: ${msg}
        </span>
        <span class="muted">
            ${new Date().toLocaleString()}
    </div>
    `;
    messages.innerHTML += content;
  };

  socketio.on("message", (data) => {
    createMessage(data.name, data.message);
  });

  const sendMessage = () => {
    console.log("send");
    const message = document.getElementById("message");
    if (message.value == "") return;
    socketio.emit("message", { data: message.value });
    message.value = "";
  };

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#message").emojioneArea({
      pickerPosition: "bottom",
    });
  });
</script>
{% for msg in messages %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  createMessage("{{ msg.name }}", "{{ msg.message }}");
</script>
{% endfor %} {% endblock %}


i tried everything with chatgpt, not working, I cant find bugs with the site console on F12.I think maybe there is a problem with the emoji script that is not configured correctly for my chatroom.
